# error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Value] /Channel/Capabilities not satisfied

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to update the capabilities to V2_0 on one of our channel. we have 2 Orgs in our channel. We have a CLI container and it has the credentials of all the orgs. I used the `peer channel signconfigtx -f config_update_in_envelope.pb` to sign the update using the admin credentials of both Org1, Org2 and I used the orderer Org credentials for performing 
 `peer channel update -f config_update_in_envelope.pb -c $CH_NAME -o $ORDERER_CONTAINER --tls true --cafile $ORDERER_CA`. 
I could see the size of the file config_update_in_envelope.pb  getting increased after I signed it using the admin credentials of Org1 and Org2.
I have used correct values for `CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH`, `CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID`  and `CORE_PEER_ADDRESS` of each org while signing  the update. But I am getting the below error.

`error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Value]  /Channel/Capabilities not satisfied: implicit policy evaluation failed - 1 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 2 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied`.

I assumed below context of each Org when performing the

```
peer channel signconfigtx -f config_update_in_envelope.pb
```

.

## Org1 Peer Details

```
export ORDERER_CONTAINER=orderer1.ord.svc.cluster.local:7050
export CH_NAME=mychannel
export CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org1.svc.cluster.local
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.svc.cluster.local:7051
export CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org1.svc.cluster.local:7051
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/artifacts/peerOrganizations/org1.svc.cluster.local/peers/peer1.org1.svc.cluster.local/tls/ca.crt
export ORDERER_CA=/etc/hyperledger/artifacts/ordererOrganizations/ord.svc.cluster.local/orderers/orderer1.ord.svc.cluster.local/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.ord.svc.cluster.local-cert.pem
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/artifacts/peerOrganizations/org1.svc.cluster.local/users/Admin@org1.svc.cluster.local/msp
```

## Org2 Peer Details

```
export CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org2.svc.cluster.local
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org2.svc.cluster.local:7051
export CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org2.svc.cluster.local:7051
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/etc/hyperledger/artifacts/peerOrganizations/org2.svc.cluster.local/peers/peer1.org2.svc.cluster.local/tls/ca.crt
export ORDERER_CA=/etc/hyperledger/artifacts/ordererOrganizations/ord.svc.cluster.local/orderers/orderer1.ord.svc.cluster.local/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.ord.svc.cluster.local-cert.pem
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/artifacts/peerOrganizations/org2.svc.cluster.local/users/Admin@org2.svc.cluster.local/msp
export CH_NAME=mychannel
```

## Orderer details

```
export ORDERER_CONTAINER=orderer1.ord.svc.cluster.local:7050
export CH_NAME=mychannel
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/artifacts/ordererOrganizations/ord.svc.cluster.local/users/Admin@ord.svc.cluster.local/msp
export ORDERER_CA="/etc/hyperledger/artifacts/ordererOrganizations/ord.svc.cluster.local/orderers/orderer1.ord.svc.cluster.local/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.ord.svc.cluster.local-cert.pem"
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=orderer1.ord.svc.cluster.local:7050
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
```

Could you please let me know if there is any more details I need to set before I sign the transaction ?. Please guide me how can I solve the issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
error authorizing update: error validating DeltaSet: policy for [Value]  /Channel/Capabilities not satisfied: implicit policy evaluation failed - 1 sub-policies were satisfied, but this policy requires 2 of the 'Admins' sub-policies to be satisfied.
```

As the above error clearly said it is a policy issue, default policy is majority of admins need to sign

seems like there are more than two organizations are present in a channel

Please be noted that `config_update_in_envelope.pb` is the updated config file need to be signed by the majority of the org admins.

You need to change the org context and sign using all majority admins

Is there any way I can verify the list of signed Orgs before I perform the peer channel update:  Try to use below snippet

```
const mySig = this.client.signChannelConfig(updated_config)
mySig.toString('utf8');
```

Comment: I have update my question with the Org context I used to sign the transaction. Could you please let me know If I miss anything ?